# Using save() function on a Model without a primary key in produces an error

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I've encountered an unusual error when using the save() function of Laravel. This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

LINE 1: ...pdate "t_h_ledger_sheet" set "o_memo1" = $1 where "" is null
                                                              ^ (SQL: update "t_h_ledger_sheet" set "o_memo1" = 1234 where "" is null)
```

Can somebody know what caused this and what can be done to fix this? Here's my Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LedgerSheet extends Model
{
    protected $table = 't_h_ledger_sheet';
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Is having no primary key causing the error?

EDIT: Here's what I did. Also an additional detail, This table must only contain 1 row of data

```
$memos = LedgerSheet::first();

if ($memos == null) {
    $memos = new LedgerSheet;
}

$o_memo1 = "ASDF";
$o_memo2 = "ASDF";
$o_memo3 = "ASDF";
$o_memo4 = "ASDF";
$o_memo5 = "asdf";
$o_memo6 = "asdf";
$o_memo7 = "asdf";
$o_memo8 = "asdf";

DB::transaction(function() use($memos, $o_memo1, $o_memo2, $o_memo3, $o_memo4, $o_memo5, $o_memo6, $o_memo7, $o_memo8) {

    $memos->o_memo1 = $o_memo1;
    $memos->o_memo2 = $o_memo2;
    $memos->o_memo3 = $o_memo3;
    $memos->o_memo4 = $o_memo4;
    $memos->o_memo5 = $o_memo5;
    $memos->o_memo6 = $o_memo6;
    $memos->o_memo7 = $o_memo7;
    $memos->o_memo8 = $o_memo8;

    try{
       $memos->save();
    }catch(\Exception $e){
       error_log($e->getMessage());   // insert query
    }

});
```

2ND EDIT REMOVING THE transaction wrap:
    $memos = LedgerSheet::first();

```
if ($memos == null) {
    $memos = new LedgerSheet;
}

$memos->o_memo1 = "ASDF";
$memos->o_memo2 = "ASDF";
$memos->o_memo3 = "ASDF";
$memos->o_memo4 = "ASDF";
$memos->o_memo5 = "asdf";
$memos->o_memo6 = "asdf";
$memos->o_memo7 = "asdf";
$memos->o_memo8 = "asdf";

try{
    $memos->save();
}catch(\Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());   // insert query
}
```

EDIT: **It is impossible to use the save() function on a Model without a primary key.**

Comment: Can you show us the query that you are trying? Because having no primary key should not cause an error.

Comment: @nakov i've edited it now

Comment: can you try by adding all the columns in a `$fillable` array like this:
`protected $fillable = ['o_memo1' ....];`  although the error that you get is a bit confusing.

Comment: @nakov Tried it. No good :(

Comment: I'm also using the version 'Laravel Framework 5.6.29'

Comment: why do you need to wrap it into a transaction when you are acting on only one table?

Comment: The usage of transaction is wrong btw, look here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#database-transactions

Comment: @nakov I've removed the transaction but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Still getting the same error? Can you please update the code above to what you have changed it?

Comment: @nakov there, edited it

Comment: Can you post your model class `LedgerSheet`?

Comment: @DavidODW it's already there posted above

Comment: Your code only shows an `INSERT` query. Where is the `UPDATE` query coming from?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I'm initializing the value to either the first row of the table or a new `LedgerSheet` model. From what I understood the `save()` function either does an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` depending on the model initialized (retrieved data or `new`) before performing the `save()` function.

Comment: You can't update the model without a primary key.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I believe you can, given the fact that you can set the primary key to null inside Eloquent models. I've also tried it with another table that doesn't have a primary key. I just don't get why this table gives off this error.

Comment: You can't: How would the database know which row to update? There is no way to identify to it. You *can* set the primary key to `null`, but that doesn't mean your model still works. Laravel can't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I believe you are correct. :o my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for PostgreSQL I believe that for you it fails at the very first line, where you are trying to get the first element because you are not setting any criteria for which to look at.

Have you tried:

```
LedgerSheet::all()->first();
```

Comment: edited the code, and it still produces the same error :(

Comment: try dumping just the `dd(LedgerSheet::all())` do you get any data out of it?

Comment: and then when you add to that `->first()` it returns the correct one or this is where it blows up?

Comment: nope, it still displays the first data and actually it produces the error when I do the save() method, not when I retrieve the data